# My beers are with a slight acid taste after the few first sips. What could be wrong?

Tags: equipment, off-flavor, taste, mill

So far I have brewed 5 times. First went perfect, though it was the first time I was using my kit and the grains were already ground. Second and third batches went wrong. My concern is with the last two batches. #4 is a pale ale, and I started opening the bottles after 7 days priming in the bottles. Fermentation went for ~7 days with fermentis US-05. For this btah I have bought a manual mill that crunches the grains by rubbing two iron discs. At first I though that this mill could be throwing some iron, and this could be the reason for this taste, but I hope that this is only because the beer is still not at it's peak. #5 is a weissbier fermented for 6 days with fermentis wb6, but has exactly this same taste at some point. It is a week younger than the pale ale, and I can tell that this acid/sour/metallic taste is a bit more characteristic in this one. Could it be something with my equipment or the way I grind the grains or is it just me that don't want to wait the time the beer need?

A few more information about the fermentation: both were rehidrated 11,5 g. packs, and kept at temperatures between 19 and 25 degrees celcius. I have moved the Pale Ale to the fridge at around 8 degrees celcius after 7 days priming in the bottles.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your fermentation practices.  Are you pitching dry yeast? are your rehydrating? what is your ambient fermentation temps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information in your post your beer sounds green to me.  Less experienced brewers tend to rush the process along, and they also have less than ideal fermentation practices.

I'd recommend you start pitching 2X packs of dry yeast, or be sure to rehydrate the one you do use in clean sterile water.

I'd also watch the fermentation temps and time.  Let your beers sit in primary for at least 10-14 days.  This is vital for proper yeast flavor development and a complete fermentation cycle.  Do not pay attention to the bubbling in the airlock and assume things are done.  There is much going on in the beer after the bubbling stops.

Lastly, be diligent with your cleaning and sanitation.  Your first batch was fine, so I'd suspect your early brewing paranoia settled out some and you aren't as careful as the first time.  Exercise patience and you will be rewarded.

Answer (score 3):

Brew Strong made a great podcast about metals in beer. http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/Brew-Strong/Brew-Strong-09-29-08-Metals-that-Affect-Your-Beer

It could potentially be some degrading or poor cleaning of your brew kettle. If your grinders blades actually touch that could definitely be it. You do want your grains to remain a little coarse. It could potentially be infected, but I doubt it. Infection would change the beer more drastically.

Answer (score 2):

**Sour** or **acidic flavor** could be a sign of a bacteria infection. The first thing to check would be your equipment.

**Metallic** flavors are likely due to an oxidizing metal which seems unlikely, unless your bottle caps are rusty.